# Tab header make transparent border for overlapping border

Tags: html, css, tabs, border

I have a border around my `.tab-content` and the same border around active `.tab`s. I've tried adding a transparent border on the bottom to no avail.

[image: my-setup]

Is there a way to, where two borders overlap, have one override the other? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jplwood/cor6xega/3/) to show my basic set up.

```css
.tab-content {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.tabs-container {
    height:auto;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#aaabbb;

}

.tabs {
    width:360px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

.tab {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 20px;
}

.tab.active {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:transparent;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-container">
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab active">This Tab</div>
        <div class="tab">That Tab</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element to create the bottom border, make it the same color as the background, and position it to cover the dark line.

```
.tab.active:after {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 10px solid #aaa;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.tab-content {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.tabs-container {
    height:auto;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#aaabbb;

}

.tabs {
    width:360px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

.tab {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 20px;
}

.tab.active {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    background-color: #aaa;
    position: relative;
}
.tab.active:after {
    content: '';
    border-bottom:10px solid #aaa;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-container">
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab active">This Tab</div>
        <div class="tab">That Tab</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
</div>
```

Or just move the whole navbar 1px down.

```
.tab.active {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    background-color: #aaa;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -1px;
}
```

```css
.tab-content {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.tabs-container {
    height:auto;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#aaabbb;

}

.tabs {
    width:360px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

.tab {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 20px;
}

.tab.active {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    background-color: #aaa;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -1px;
}
/* .tab.active:after {
    content: '';
    border-bottom:10px solid #aaa;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
} */
```

```html
<div class="tabs-container">
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab active">This Tab</div>
        <div class="tab">That Tab</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pangloss! This works pretty well but it still leaves a tiny sliver of a line in Chrome and extending the bottom to -2px to completely cover it makes the left and right borders stick out down below the line (Works perfectly in Firefox).

Comment: I dunno, might be my OS or screen or something. It changes in noticeability when zooming in and out, but you can see it here - http://i.imgur.com/P9n2XMh.png But it's not that big of a deal. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It gonna be hard to debug, as I can't see that extra line here. Try the first pseudo element approach, and set to `bottom:-2px;` or so.